# Asp.NET Web API throwing 404 instead of 400

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, http-error

I have built a service in .NET 4.5 and Entity Framework 6, using the ASP.NET Web API template. When I make a GET request to the service and omit a required parameter, it is returning a 404 - Not Found, instead of a 400 - Bad Request. I tried checking to see if the required parameters are null, but it's not even reaching the code inside the method (see code below). My question is how do I change the default response or make it return 400 for missing required parameters.

```
[Route("item")]
[HttpGet]
public IHttpActionResult GetItem(string reqParam1, string reqParam2)
{
    if (reqParam1 == null || reqParam2 == null)
        throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);

    //remainder of code here
}
```

Here is the webAPI.config file. I don't think that I have modified it from the default.

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Just a note: the API isn't accessing information such as item/electronics/tvs but more like items where item is green and is square, where those descriptions are mandatory to pass in - so the query is like `/item?color=green&shape=square`.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, the 404 is an appropriate response. The caller is looking for a method on the API that takes one argument. No such method exists so the framework is responding with a 404. This is happening upstream of your code, in the framework itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server returns a 404 because it cannot find the route you are trying to access. Actually the arguments should be a part of your route, as optionals or not: `Route("items/{reqParam1}/{reqParam2}")`

If you defined them as optionals the route should still be called if you use just `items` and you can throw the BadRequest. If not optionals then probably the NotFound will still be thrown.

You should also post the webApi config, so that we can see the base route mapping.

**EDIT**
take the following route example:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "RunsWithParams",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{project}/{skip}/{take}",
            defaults: new { take = RouteParameter.Optional, skip = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

the project param is mandatory, the remaining are optional. you can call with just the project, or the remaining, and if you use just one of the Optionals then 404 is thrown, because the route is not defined.
This is the same as using the decorators, so it does not exactly solve your issue, but explains a bit better the routing. Still, I don't see why you need a BadRequest in particular.

**Yet another edit:**

To use the request url parameters as you mention at the end of the post, you just need to use the [FromUri] decorator, see [this page](http://www.strathweb.com/2013/04/asp-net-web-api-parameter-binding-part-1-understanding-binding-from-uri/) for more details, and a breef example follows:

```
// POST api/files/{project}?target={target}
public HttpResponseMessage Post(string project, string target, [FromUri]string fname){...}
```

Comment: I added the config file, which i haven't modified yet, so if I am correct, I'll need to add some code here to fix the issue. Is that what you were saying?

Comment: it's just requirements for the project. if there is a missing argument or the argument variable is misspelled (which also returns 404 here), the api should return 400 - Bad Request. They only want 404 if the value of an argument is misspelled or incorrect in some fashion.